# jQuery form validation not working in several if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a problem with jQuery validation.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="#" name="validate" onsubmit="return validateRegistration();">
   <input type="text" id="username" value="Username" />
   <input type="text" id="email" value="Email" />
   <input type="text" id="phone" value="Phone" />
</form>

function validateRegistration() {

    var username = $('#username').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
        var phone = $('#phone').val();

    if(username=='' || username == 'Username'){
       $('#username').after('<span class="error">Enter a username</span>');
    }

    if(email=='' || email == 'Email'){
       $('#email').after('<span class="error">Please enter a valid email address</span>');
    }

    if(phone=='' || phone == 'Phone'){
       $('#phone').after('<span class="error">This field is required.</span>');
       return false;
    }
}
```

Validation works when the form has no values in it. And if I fill only phone fields, the form submits with `return true`. I can't put `return false` in all fields, since all the validation errors should be visible at a time. The code I have given is short and original. I have more than 30 fields, so any major variation is a pain. Any help?

Comment: try to clear values of variables `function validateRegistration() {var username = ("");
        var email =("");
            var phone = ("")}`

Comment: Please be more careful when tagging your questions.  This has nothing to do with the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sparky Sorry I never know that tag is for jQuery-validate plugin. I will take care of it in furture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function validateRegistration() {
        var notError = true;
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
            var phone = $('#phone').val();

        if(username=='' || username == 'Username'){
           $('#username').after('<span class="error">Enter a username</span>');
           notError = false;
        }

        if(email=='' || email == 'Email'){
           $('#email').after('<span class="error">Please enter a valid email address</span>');
           notError = false;
        }

        if(phone=='' || phone == 'Phone'){
           $('#phone').after('<span class="error">This field is required.</span>');
           notError = false;
        }

        return notError;
    }
```

Hope this will satisfy your need